# Can anybody tell the if file doesn't exists it redirect to webinstaller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

Can anybody tell the if file doesn't exists  it redirect to webinstall. How to go the redirection to webinstaller url in laravel when i deleting the .env file is 500 error

Answer (score 0):

you can write it in Handler.php of Exception directory